# How to import csv files into Mongo?

Tags: mongodb, bash, shell, mongo-shell, mongoimport

I want to import csv files into MongoDB.
I found that there is a command "mongoimport" to import files.

Based on [mongoimport documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongoimport/) I have installed the [Database Tools](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/installation/installation/) for [Windows](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/installation/installation-windows/):

I put on PATH of Environment Variables:

`C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Tools\100\bin`

and then I have restarted the PC.

I have created a bash script to execute mongoimport for all the csv files into the script directory:

```
#!/bin/bash

HOST="00.00.000.00:00000"                                                                                                             
USERNAME="user"
PASSWORD="password"
DB_NAME="mydb"

CSV_EXTENSION=".csv"

# Get the directory path of the script
SCRIPT_DIRECTORY=$(pwd)

for fullFilePath in "$SCRIPT_DIRECTORY"/*
do
  
  filename="${fullFilePath##*/}"                                  
  
  fileNameWithoutExtension="${filename%.[^.]*}"                   

  fileExtension="${filename:${#fileNameWithoutExtension}}"        

  fileExtensionLowerCase=${fileExtension,,}
  
  if [ "$fileExtensionLowerCase" == "$CSV_EXTENSION" ]; then
  
      echo "importing collection: $fileNameWithoutExtension ..."
      
      mongoimport --db=$DB_NAME --collection=$fileNameWithoutExtension --type csv --headerline --file=$fullFilePath --host=$HOST -u=$USERNAME -p=$PASSWORD --authenticationDatabase=admin
  fi
  
done
```

When I execute the script I got

```
$ ./Import_File_On_Mongo.sh
importing collection: Test ...
2023-10-06T17:49:03.612+0200    error parsing command line options: error parsing positional arguments: provide only one file name and only one MongoDB connection string. Connection strings must begin with mongodb:// or mongodb+srv:// schemes
```

Comment: `monogimport.exe` ?

Comment: All variables should be double quoted `--db="$DB_NAME" --collection="$fileNameWithoutExtension" ....`. It's a good measure to check scripts on https://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: I assume your user/password is not actually "user"/"password".  Do they contain any spaces or shell reactive characters?

Comment: @Joe no, user and password don't contain any spaces, only chars A-Z

Comment: I think you need to pass the arguments either as `-u $USERNAME` or `--username=$USERNAME`. Anyway, I would suggest to use [Connection String](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/reference/connection-string/#std-label-connections-standard-connection-string-format)

Comment: @LMC Thanks, I have solved the issue by double quoting variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake was the missing double quotes on variables (as mentioned by @LMC on comments).

I have then added the authenticationMechanism cause I'm using SCRAM-SHA-256, and the default one is SCRAM-SHA-1.

```
#!/bin/bash

HOST="00.00.000.00:00000"                                                                                                             
USERNAME="user"
PASSWORD="password"
DB_NAME="mydb"

CSV_EXTENSION=".csv"

# Get the directory path of the script
SCRIPT_DIRECTORY="$(pwd)"

for fullFilePath in "$SCRIPT_DIRECTORY"/*
do
  
  fileName="${fullFilePath##*/}"
  
  fileNameWithoutExtension="${fileName%.[^.]*}"
  
  fileExtension="${fileName:${#fileNameWithoutExtension}}"
  fileExtensionLowerCase="${fileExtension,,}"
  
  if [ "$fileExtensionLowerCase" == "$CSV_EXTENSION" ]; then
  
      echo "importing collection: $fileNameWithoutExtension ..."
      
      mongoimport --file="$fullFilePath" --type csv --headerline --db="$DB_NAME" --collection="$fileNameWithoutExtension" --host="$HOST" -u="$USERNAME" -p="$PASSWORD" --authenticationMechanism SCRAM-SHA-256 --authenticationDatabase admin

  fi
  
done
```